# TopicClient Service Bus hangs

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have very weird issue while trying to send message to azure service bus topic.

```
 TopicClient topicClient = 
     TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString, 
     TopicName);
```

This is inside a webapi project . My code just hangs on this line, and does not creates TopicClient.

Now If I use the same code with same connectionstring and topicname in console application, it works perfect.

At loss to troubleshoot. Network issue is ruled out as well.

Anyone faced this before?

Comment: I can't see your code, but are you blocking on async calls? With `.Result` maybe?

Comment: This is first line on my code, and method isnt async either.

Comment: What client (nuget) package are you using? If this is `Windowsazure.ServiceBus`, the default connectivity is TCP and then falls back to HTTPS. Try changing connectivity mode to HTTPS and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exacts same problem with

```
QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(...)
```

Updating Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging nuget to the latest version solved the issue.